# optimize.minimize function, difference in Jupyter notebook and python?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, jupyter-notebook, minimize

I am writing a code that takes some data, and fits the data using a model with 5 unknown parameters.

I give some initial values of these parameters. I minimize the difference between the data and a model (chi^2 function) with an optimize.minimize function to obtain the best-fit values of these parameters.

I run the codes in Jupyter notebook and python script. However, the results are different. Jupyter notebook gives a much better fit. In the python script the fit is not very good and the resulting values of the unknown parameters seem not to change a lot from the initial values (with some parameters staying constant)

I tried looking at the documentations of the two different versions of the optimize.minimize functions which are installed in Jupyter (0.19.1) and python (0.18.0).

I checked the arguments' values but they are all the same for the two functions (both set by me and the default values).

likelihood funciton:

```
def ds_lnlike(par, logm, d, d_err):
    logms, ds1, ds2, a1, a2 = par     
    model= np.log(10)*(ds1*10**((a1 + 1)*(logm - logms)) + ds2*10**((a2 +1)*(logm - logms)))/np.e**(10**(logm - logms))
    return -0.5*np.sum(((d-model)**2)/d_err**2)
```

optimize.minimize:

```
nll = lambda *args: -model.ds_lnlike(*args) 
result = op.minimize(nll, [logms[j], ds1[j], ds2[j], a1[j], a2[j]], args=(x, y, dy), method='TNC', bounds = ((7,13),(0, 0.1),(0, 0.1), (-2, 4), (-2, -1)), tol=1.0e-4)
logms[j], ds1[j], ds2[j], a1[j], a2[j] = result["x"]
```

initial values: `10.7 1.0e-3 0.5e-3 -0.5 -1.5`

Jupyter values: `1.07708741e+01, 6.59697230e-03, 9.48211306e-04, -3.37329546e-01, -1.57843904e+00`

python values: `10.699999999999999, 0.0062248066587528919, 0.0012695745516126539, -0.5, -1.5`

Comment: What version is this: `python (0.18.0)`? Is Jupyter and Python running in same environment on same data? Please show full script and not code snippets including import lines and data assignment (i.e., [MCVE]).

Comment: 0.18.0 is a scipy version installed. Jupyter and python are not in the same environment